# How to change Scada-LTS to ROOT / ROOT.war

Tags: scadalts

in docker.
When I change the Scada-LTS.war file to ROOT.war, the site doesn't respond correctly. Script tab does not finish loading.
and a popup window always appears on all tabs.
It is possible to deploy Scada-LTS web application at the root of a Tomcat?
thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEt5M.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlbGy.jpg)

Try to copy and paste the Scada-LTS.war to ROOT.war
I also renamed the webapps/Scada-LTS folder to webapps/ROOT but the problem persists